# WPF take up less space than * if content is smaller

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, grid, resize

I have some user control whose content is something like a table. If you look at the XAML, MainGrid actually represent the 'table'.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    ...

    <ScrollViewer AutomationProperties.AutomationId="SchedulerScrolViewer" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

MainGrid is in a scroll viewer, because I can have 100 rows and 100 columns for example, and for that case code works just fine.
But, please consider next case.

Available window height is for example 500 pixels. In the MainGrid I have two rows, which height is 25. So I want that my MainGrid take only 50 pixels(25,25) and that 450 pixels be unused.

Because of `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` I actually get that MainGrid take 500 pixels(25, 475). How can I change such a behavior?

I thought about something like this

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding CalculatedHeight}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding CalculatedWidth}" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

CalculatedHeight will be calculated on next way

```
if(content height > main grid actual height)
{
    CalculatedHeight = main grid actual height; // I need scroll viewer
}
else
{
    CalculatedHeight = content height;
}
```

But in that case, I must watch over window expanders(if expander is expanded I have less space), resizing etc. and I'm not sure is that a good way.

If I set `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" />` scroll viewer doesn't work because Auto means that a row is given as much height as the elements within it require.

Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: What about setting the Height of the ScrollViewer to 50 and the Height of the second RowDefinition to Auto (or 50)?

Comment: But problem with window resizing or expanding the expander is still present.

Comment: Please provide a full repo of your issue when you ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="OuterGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=InnerGrid, Path=ActualHeight, FallbackValue=1}" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">sdfsdfs</TextBlock>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid x:Name="InnerGrid" Height="Auto">
            <TextBlock>
                jhdsfksjdhf
                <LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak /><LineBreak />
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The `FallBackValue` is needed for initial Height...

Comment: Thank you! I find out another solution also, so if you are curious take a look in answers.

Answer (score 1):

I find out a really simple solution. Key part is VerticalAlignment="Top".

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<TextBlock Grid.Row="0">...</TextBlock>

<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```